# Lavachart - can not set property of "style" of null

Tags: laravel

I just started using this library in laravel but it seems that it's not working.

This is the controller's code used:

```
$entries = \Lava::DataTable();
    $query = Survey::select('country AS 0', \DB::raw('count(country) AS entries'))->groupBy('country')->get()->toArray();

    $data = [];

    foreach ($query as $q) {
        $data[] = [$q[0], $q['entries']];
    }


    $entries->addStringColumn('Country')
               ->addNumberColumn('Popularity')
               ->addRows($data);

    \Lava::GeoChart('Popularity', $entries);



    return view('dashboard.homepage', ['colorsNum' => $colorsNum]);
```

This is my blade file:

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div id="pop-div"></div>
                  @geochart('Popularity', 'pop-div')
                </div>
           </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUgKT.png)

It's showing this red error: **Cannot read property 'style' of null**

I don't know what's going wrong so please if you can help me, your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your data is not actual formatted as a chart. That's why it shows this error

Comment: I tried to put data directly using ->addRow(array('Germany', 200));, still not working, so I don't think it's the data. Thanks!

Comment: Which type of data support in your chart please check. Sometimes it can be `json` type also

Comment: I inspected the HTML and this is what appears "google-visualization-errors-all-1", the class of the div with the error. So this is a deeper problem, I already checked real working examples to it's not the data type, it's only that for me no example is working.

Comment: I gave up and used google chart map directly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the by passing the third parameter options

```
$lava->GeoChart('Popularity', $popularity,  [
        'colorAxis'                 =>  [ 'minValue' => 0,  'colors' => ['#FF0000', '#00FF00']],   //ColorAxis Options
        'datalessRegionColor'       => '#81d4fa',
        'displayMode'               => 'auto',
        'enableRegionInteractivity' => true,
        'keepAspectRatio'           => true,
        'region'                    => 'world',
        'magnifyingGlass'           => ['enable' => true, 'zoomFactor' => 7.5],    //MagnifyingGlass Options
        'markerOpacity'             => 1.0,
        'resolution'                => 'countries',
        'sizeAxis'                  => null ,
        'backgroundColor'=> '#81d4fa',
        
    ]);
```

Comment: So this is some sort of bug because using the examples provided it did not work at all, thanks!